# SMTP not connect with port 25

Tags: php, smtp, email-verification

when i try to check any email address exist or not by SMTP by PHP script.
getting following error.......

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtesting\verify-gmail-address-via-smtp\lib\smtp_validateEmail.class.php on line 154
>
> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtesting\verify-gmail-address-via-smtp\lib\smtp_validateEmail.class.php on line 154
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtesting\verify-gmail-address-via-smtp\lib\smtp_validateEmail.class.php on line 154

**I used smtp_validateEmail.class.php library**

Comment: Try another port then (Google has a few you can use, and may not be accessible through 25). You also have no code which makes it that much more harder to potentially help/solve this.

Comment: i used "smtp_validateEmail.class.php library" for verify email address but it getting this error.

Comment: Re-read my comment up there ;-) Plus, all you did was post errors but no code and only stating you're using a library file. You're also using this from localhost so make sure you can use that port. Read the Google/Gmail API docs also. There isn't anything else I can add here, good luck.